# How get name macros from value?

Tags: c++, macros, c++20

I write #define macros

I want to have a function or a macro that prints its name when I give it a value

for example :

`

```
#define ten 10

 string printName(int value);
int main()
{
    cout<<printName(10);
}
```

`

```
output : ten
```

A solution or code sample

Comment: What name? Do you mean print the number using words? Well, what have you tried so far? This is not code-writing service.

Comment: Give me the number of macros and return the name to me

Comment: Okay, and what did you try so far? What problems are you having with your solution?

Comment: The general rule for C++ is NOT to use since macros are not typesafe (unless you have to). In this case `static constexpr int ten{10};'`  would be a better approach to define a constant.  Side note, stop using [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of macros should be avoided wherever possible.

Instead you could use a `std::map<int, std::string>` for your purpose:

```
int main()
{
    const std::map<int, std::string> printName{{10, "ten"}, {11, "eleven"}};//add more if you want 
    
    std::cout << printName.at(10) << std::endl;  //prints ten
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pre processor doesn't allow what you are trying to do

Also consider:

```
#define ten 10
#define xxx 10

string printName(int value);
int main()
{
    cout<<printName(10);
}
```

What would you expect it to output ? Just because it makes sense to you doesn't mean it makes sense to the compiler / cpp.